# asp.net button hover not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

This is the code and css i have checked several links and followed accordingly but i still get the problem. Kindly explain.

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" BackColor="#93C323" 
            Font-Names="Segoe UI Light" Font-Size="X-Large" ForeColor="White" Height="41px" 
            style="margin-left: 144px" Text="+ Add" Width="121px" />

.button:hover
{
 background:#DBDBDB;
}
```

Comment: Your css needs to be in <style> tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Avoid to make the style inline when you like to change it by hover, or dynamically. This is an example that I just tested and is working:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" CssClass="OneButton" Text="ok" />

    <style type="text/css">
        .OneButton
        {
            background-color:#93C323;
            font-size:x-large;
            color:White;
            height:41px;
            width:121px;
            margin-left:144px;
        }

        .OneButton:hover
        {
            background-color:#DBDBDB;
        }    
    </style>
```

And a live version of it: http://jsfiddle.net/gwSWy/

Comment: Nice one, more complete answer than mine.

Comment: @nimeshjm Yours is fine, I just asked to quick give a fully working answer. The issues here is not only the CssClass, also the background only is not give the correct color. And the style is better to not be inline.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add cssclass="button" to your button.

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" BackColor="#93C323" CssClass="button"
            Font-Names="Segoe UI Light" Font-Size="X-Large" ForeColor="White" Height="41px" 
            style="margin-left: 144px" Text="+ Add" Width="121px" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to do this globally for all buttons:

The ASP.NET button creates `<input type="submit">`.

So you'll need to style around that.

Comment: No i just need it for this button.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need that style with your button, you can use the Button Property `CssClass`. Check this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.cssclass.aspx) for your reference.

and one thing more, I guess you're not using `style` properly. you can just put your `margin` details in the `button` css then remove the attribute style.

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS rule will not find the element in the DOM because there is no CSS class assigned to it the way you are doing it.

You can do as nimeshjm mentioned and add the CssClass="button" attribute to the button control - this should match your CSS rule assuming you don't have any other problems (stylesheet is linked to on the page, no over-riding/more specific rules.

You also won't be able to style the element based on its ID because it will be automatically changed when the page is rendered to prevent ID collisions between elements.

If you use the attribute `ClientIDMode="Static"` which will keep the ID as you specified in the control.

As Joe Enos stated, the Button control is rendered as an `<input type-"submit" />` so you also can't use an CSS rule like `button:hover { background: black; }`